# Authorization middleware doesn't recognize policies added through MVC conventions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization

This is an ASP.NET Core 3.1 web application. I'm adding policies to my `ApiController` read/write methods using code adapted from [this blog post](https://dejanstojanovic.net/aspnet/2019/april/why-you-should-not-use-authorize-attributes-to-protect-your-api-endpoints/):

```
public class DefaultApiAuthorizationConvention : IActionModelConvention
{
    private readonly string _apiReadPolicyName;
    private readonly string _apiWritePolicyName;

    public DefaultApiAuthorizationConvention(string apiReadPolicyName = Constants.POLICY_API_READ, string apiWritePolicyName = Constants.POLICY_API_WRITE)
    {
        _apiReadPolicyName = apiReadPolicyName;
        _apiWritePolicyName = apiWritePolicyName;
    }

    public void Apply(ActionModel action)
    {
        // only apply to API controllers
        if (!action.Controller.Attributes.Any(a => a is ApiControllerAttribute))
            return;

        // Require API Write policy for POST/PUT/DELETE methods, and API Read policy for GET methods
        if (action.Attributes.Any(a => a is HttpPostAttribute || a is HttpPutAttribute || a is HttpDeleteAttribute))
        {
            action.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy: _apiWritePolicyName));
        }
        else if (action.Attributes.Any(a => a is HttpGetAttribute))
        {
            action.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy: _apiReadPolicyName));
        }
    }
}
```

The convention is added and the policies are registered in `Startup.cs`, and that's all fine and dandy. I also have default and fallback policies defined.

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.Add(new AppAuth.DefaultApiAuthorizationConvention());
});
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .RequireRole(WebConstants.ROLE_SITE_ADMIN, WebConstants.ROLE_SITE_BROWSER)
        .Build();
    // general API policy
    options.AddPolicy(AppAuth.Constants.POLICY_API_READ, policy => 
        policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser()
              .RequireRole(WebConstants.ROLE_SITE_ADMIN, WebConstants.ROLE_API_READ));
    options.AddPolicy(AppAuth.Constants.POLICY_API_WRITE, policy => 
        policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser()
              .RequireRole(WebConstants.ROLE_SITE_ADMIN, WebConstants.ROLE_API_WRITE));
    // other policies omitted
});
```

The controller is like so, with no `[Authorize]` attribute on either the controller or method.

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        return Ok(await _service.Get());
    }
}
```

The problem is that when a user who is a member of `ROLE_API_READ` as per the policy calls the API method, the [AuthorizationMiddleware](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Security/Authorization/Policy/src/AuthorizationMiddleware.cs) always marks them as unauthorized.

Investigating the source code of the middleware, we find:

```
var authorizeData = endpoint?.Metadata.GetOrderedMetadata<IAuthorizeData>() ?? Array.Empty<IAuthorizeData>();
```

I made a copy of the class in my project so I could debug, and when I put a break point here, `authorizeData` turned out to be a an empty array. So then we check the [EndpointMetadataCollection](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/86ea8e019eb315dd6b68bd7fcc796a0fcb6a67c9/src/Http/Http.Abstractions/src/Routing/EndpointMetadataCollection.cs#L101) class:

```
public IReadOnlyList<T> GetOrderedMetadata<T>() where T : class
{
    if (_cache.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out var result))
    {
        return (T[])result;
    }
    return GetOrderedMetadataSlow<T>(); // private method that gets the metadata real-time
}
```

This `_cache` variable is set in the constructor and contains the empty array of `IAuthorizeData`:
[image: No IAuthorizeData in the Metadata class]

The `Metadata` object itself contains the `AuthorizeFilter` as added by the convention:
[image]

I did contact the blog author, who surprisingly doesn't appear to be an Stack Overflow, but I wanted to open it to the wider community to see what my options were.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filters aren't the same as endpoint metadata. You need to write a convention that mutates the `SelectorModel` on the `ActionModel`:

```cs
public class DefaultApiAuthorizationConvention : IActionModelConvention
{
    private readonly string _apiReadPolicyName;
    private readonly string _apiWritePolicyName;

    public DefaultApiAuthorizationConvention(string apiReadPolicyName = Constants.POLICY_API_READ, string apiWritePolicyName = Constants.POLICY_API_WRITE)
    {
        _apiReadPolicyName = apiReadPolicyName;
        _apiWritePolicyName = apiWritePolicyName;
    }

    public void Apply(ActionModel action)
    {
        // only apply to API controllers
        if (!action.Controller.Attributes.Any(a => a is ApiControllerAttribute))
            return;

        // Require API Write policy for POST/PUT/DELETE methods, and API Read policy for GET methods
        if (action.Attributes.Any(a => a is HttpPostAttribute || a is HttpPutAttribute || a is HttpDeleteAttribute))
        {
            foreach (var s in action.Selectors)
            {
                s.EndpointMetadata.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute(_apiWritePolicyName));
            }
        }
        else if (action.Attributes.Any(a => a is HttpGetAttribute))
        {
            foreach (var s in action.Selectors)
            {
                s.EndpointMetadata.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute(_apiReadPolicyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

PS: Auth was re-written in ASP.NET Core 3.0 to be based on endpoint metadata and MVC filters are no longer used by default.